# Adding posts updates previous post

Tags: posts

Intermittently adding a new post will cause the previous post to be updated with the new posts information, instead of it being inserted.
The the _posts table it looks like a normal revision of an old post but it was definitely added via the add new post page.

Wordpress version 5.2.1
Adding the post manually through wp-admin. Not using code. Only happens with editor user, can't make it happen with admin. Tried deleting user and making a new one but same problem.

Below is the _posts table after “adding” 6 posts, as you can see test post_4 is updated by test post_5. So there only ends up with 5 posts instead of 6.

```
id  post_date   post_title  post_status post_name   post_parent post_type
1145    2019-06-14 13:22:44 test post_6 publish test-post_6 0   post
1146    2019-06-14 13:22:44 test post_6 inherit 1145-revision-v1    1145    revision
1144    2019-06-14 13:22:31 test post_5 inherit 1142-revision-v1    1142    revision
1142    2019-06-14 13:22:19 test post_5 publish test-post_4 0   post
1143    2019-06-14 13:22:19 test post_4 inherit 1142-revision-v1    1142    revision
1140    2019-06-14 13:22:08 test post_3 publish test-post_3 0   post
1141    2019-06-14 13:22:08 test post_3 inherit 1140-revision-v1    1140    revision
1138    2019-06-14 13:21:58 test post_2 publish test-post_2 0   post
1139    2019-06-14 13:21:58 test post_2 inherit 1138-revision-v1    1138    revision
1136    2019-06-14 13:21:44 test post_1 publish test-post_1 0   post
1137    2019-06-14 13:21:44 test post_1 inherit 1136-revision-v1    1136    revision
```

Any ideas what the cause of this could be?

Comment: how are you adding the posts? There's no code in your question :(

Comment: Adding the post manually through wp-admin. Not using code.

Comment: There is probably code somewhere causing this to happen; try disabling plugins and switching themes to narrow it down.